# R : Display Image at Exact Node in Igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am able to put images at node in graph, but the image is not showing at exact place. Here I have attached the demo code which has problem in displaying the images at exact node. Images are interchanged their position even the logic behind is correct. Please improve the code so that I can work further

**Note : With less number of nodes codes are working fine**.

```
################ R Code To implement dynamic image fetching  #######################
library(jpeg)
library(igraph) 

demo_adj <- data.frame(from=c(1,2,'B','X','Y',1,1,'A'),to=c('A','B','A','Y',1,'B','X',2))

rasters <- as.list(c(imgType1='',imgType2='',imgType3='',imgType4='',imgType5=''))

rasters$imgType1 <- readJPEG("path/Images/imgType1.jpg",native=TRUE)
rasters$imgType2 <- readJPEG("path/Images/imgType2.jpg",native=TRUE)
rasters$imgType3 <- readJPEG("path/Images/imgType3.jpg",native=TRUE)
rasters$imgType4 <- readJPEG("path/Images/imgType4.jpg",native=TRUE)
rasters$imgType5 <- readJPEG("path/Images/imgType5.jpg",native=TRUE)

lkp_mat <- data.frame(from=c(1,2,'A','B','X','Y'),type=c('imgType1','imgType2','imgType3','imgType4','imgType1','imgType3'))



## create the graph
gg <- graph.data.frame(demo_adj)
## set raster attribute
for(i in V(gg)$name){
                imgtype <- lkp_mat$type[lkp_mat["from"]==i]
                V(gg)[name==i]$raster <- rasters[imgtype]
}
plot(gg, layout=layout.star, vertex.shape="raster",
     vertex.label=V(gg)$name, margin=.2,
     vertex.size=50, vertex.size2=50,
     vertex.label.dist=2, vertex.label.degree=0)
###################### End of Above Code Segment ###########################################
```

**Alternatively**

If don't want to get jpeg images from your disk then please use following code for the above written problems : Here you can look that node name 5 and few other nodes are not displaying the right image. Please distinguish the images as it is not very distinguishable

```
###### Alternate Code To implement the above without jpeg images   #######

library(jpeg)
library(igraph) 

demo_adj <- data.frame(from=c(1,2,3,4,5,'F','G','H','I','J','J'),to=c('A','B','C','D','E',1,2,3,4,3,5))

rasters <- as.list(c(imgType1='',imgType2='',imgType3='',imgType4='',imgType5='',imgType6='',imgType7='',imgType8='',imgType9='',imgType10='',imgType11='',imgType12='',imgType13='',imgType14='',imgType15=''))
image1 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=1, nrow=2))
image2 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=2, nrow=4))
image3 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=1, nrow=4))
image4 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=4, nrow=4))
image5 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=4, nrow=10))
image6 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=2, nrow=2))
image7 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=2, nrow=3))
image8 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=2, nrow=4))
image9 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=2, nrow=5))
image10 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=2, nrow=6))
image11 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=3, nrow=2))
image12 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=4, nrow=8))
image13 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=3, nrow=4))
image14 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=4, nrow=2))
image15 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=4, nrow=10))

rasters$imgType1 <- image1
rasters$imgType2 <- image2
rasters$imgType3 <- image3
rasters$imgType4 <- image4
rasters$imgType5 <- image5
rasters$imgType6 <- image6
rasters$imgType7 <- image7
rasters$imgType8 <- image8
rasters$imgType9 <- image9
rasters$imgType10 <- image10
rasters$imgType11 <- image11
rasters$imgType12 <- image12
rasters$imgType13 <- image13
rasters$imgType14 <- image14
rasters$imgType15 <- image15

lkp_mat <- data.frame(from=c(1,2,3,4,5,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'),type=c('imgType1','imgType2','imgType3','imgType4','imgType5','imgType6','imgType7','imgType8','imgType9','imgType10','imgType11','imgType12','imgType13','imgType14','imgType15'))
#lkp_mat <- data.frame(from=c(1,2,3,4,5,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'),type=c('imgType1','imgType2','imgType3','imgType4','imgType5','imgType2','imgType1','imgType2','imgType1','imgType2','imgType1','imgType2','imgType1','imgType2','imgType15'))

## create the graph
gg <- graph.data.frame(demo_adj)
## set raster attribute
for(i in V(gg)$name){
                imgtype <- lkp_mat$type[lkp_mat["from"]==i]
                V(gg)[name==i]$raster <- rasters[imgtype]
}
plot(gg, layout=layout.star, vertex.shape="raster",
     vertex.label=V(gg)$name, margin=.2,
     vertex.size=10, vertex.size2=20,
     vertex.label.dist=2, vertex.label.degree=0)
```

Below is the problem image
[image]

Comment: any suggestion are welcomed from masters of technology

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863754/display-image-at-exact-node-in-igraph-in-r Why two questions for seemingly the same thing?

Comment: previous question was not answered, and I have change the alternate code in the second segment of post ( which can be runned without jpeg images)

Comment: You can edit a question, you don't have to post a new one. You could delete the other one, then.

Comment: Ok, I have deleted the last one , please help in the above problem

Comment: Please answer the above question, or suggest the enhancement for question itself

Comment: I am actually not sure what is the problem. The images look OK for me. Can you insert an image that you get and tell me what exactly is wrong?

Comment: @GaborCsardi Here I have attached the image, In Code
image5 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=4, nrow=10))
image15 <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=4, nrow=10))
image5 and image15 are same, but after plot they will not look like that on node 5 the shown image is as of node 1, not of node J.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has not much to do with igraph, but it is a deadly R catch, featured in the [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf),  Section 8.2.6, do not subscript with factors.

Take a look at this part from your code, with some debugging added:

```
for(i in V(gg)$name){
  imgtype <- lkp_mat$type[lkp_mat["from"]==i]
  V(gg)[name==i]$raster <- rasters[imgtype]
  if (i=="J") { 
    print(rasters[imgtype]) ; 
    print(rasters[as.character(imgtype)]) 
  }
}
```

Btw. the whole thing could be a lot simpler, if you used the `vertices` argument of `graph.data.frame()`, e.g. something like this:

```
gg2 <- graph.data.frame(demo_adj, vertices=lkp_mat)
V(gg2)$raster <- rasters[V(gg2)$type]

plot(gg2, layout=layout.star, vertex.shape="raster",
     vertex.label=V(gg2)$name, margin=.2,
     vertex.size=10, vertex.size2=20,
     vertex.label.dist=2, vertex.label.degree=0)
```

Comment: Thanks Gabor, the problem seems to be handled from the given suggestion.